# Returning Swift Dictionary as AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift

```
 func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return [
            "name": title,
            "addedByUser": subtitle,
            "completed": imageURL
        ]
    }
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

UPDATE: I am trying to create the toAnyObject function and utilize it in a Firebase application. I get the following:

```
, reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at name. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

 let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let categoriesRef = rootRef.child("categories")

        let annuals = FlowerCategory(id: 1, title: "Annuals",subtitle :"Plants that just last one season. These plants will die in the winter. ", imageURL: "annuals.jpg")
        let perennials = FlowerCategory(id: 2, title: "Perennials",subtitle :"Plants come back year after year. These are also very less expensive", imageURL: "Perennial.jpg")

        let flowerCategories = [annuals,perennials]

        for flowerCategory in flowerCategories {

            let categoryRef = categoriesRef.child("category")
            categoryRef.setValue(flowerCategory.toAnyObject())  <- THIS LINE ERROR

        }
```

Comment: `return [
            "name": title,
            "addedByUser": subtitle,
            "completed": imageURL
        ] as AnyObject`

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is a **value type** in swift. And `AnyObject` only accepts **reference types**.

So in order to return a `Dictionary` use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`.

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "name": title,
            "addedByUser": subtitle,
            "completed": imageURL
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of categoryRef?

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to `NSDictionary`:

```
func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
    return [
        "name": title,
        "addedByUser": subtitle,
        "completed": imageURL
    ] as NSDictionary
}
```